# D3 opacity transition shows erratic behavior, sometimes working and sometimes not

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to make a tooltip show on hover, which I've gotten to work, however, its behavior isn't consistent. Sometimes, the opacity goes from 0 to 1 normally on hover, and sometimes it goes from 0, to a very small number (0.00001 or something like that), then back to 0, never reaching 1. Moving the mouse around the object doesn't re-trigger it, only moving it outside and then back into the object. It may be the styling that is affecting this:

```
var node = svg
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", n => n.job.color)
    .on("mouseover", function(event,d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 1)
          div.html("Job title: " + d.job.name)
          .style("position", "absolute")
          .style("text-align", "center")
          .style("padding", "5px")
          .style("background", "white")
          .style("border", "solid")
          .style("border-width", "2px")
          .style("border-radius", "5px")
          .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

If I comment out the lines starting from `.style("position", "absolute)` through `.style("border-radius", "5px")`, it works consistently, however, all the styling is gone and I do need it. I haven't been able to make it work through an external CSS file so it's done in-line until I can figure out how to make it work. I've tried commenting out each specific line separately as well, and none of them definitively fix the problem.

Comment: This will almost certainly not get an answer unless you provide a [mcve]. Without the chance to reproduce the error it comes down to mere guessing.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to provide one; I'm rendering a node-edge graph with the tooltip displaying when you hover on any node. The graph itself is built in 3 separate files; I've provided a larger snippet of the entire node initialization but I'm not sure if that's reproducible.

Comment: I'd avoid using a transition on mouseover. try to use mouseenter instead. Another thing that you can try is using a css transition. If you can do it with css, dont use d3.transition

Comment: Thank you! Not sure what exactly fixed it but I made a bunch of changes to how the function is defined/called and made all the CSS run from an external stylesheet file, and it's working consistently now.

Answer (score -1):

Change the order function calls and make transition the last one:

```
div.html("Job title: " + d.job.name)
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("padding", "5px")
  .style("background", "white")
  .style("border", "solid")
  .style("border-width", "2px")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(200)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```